# how to get the unique string from the data frame column using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

splited_Unique is the column name in my dataframe
[check the sample data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13Naq.png)

sample data looks like this

```
8,8
6,7
7,7
7,6
2,12
12,3
3,4
4,12
12,12
14,14
1,1
1,12
12,2
2,2
2,4
6,8
8,8
8,12
6,6
6,3
3,14
1,14
14,14
14,1
1,1
1,2
1,1
1,14
2,2
2,15
15,5
5,5
5,16
1,11


unique_list = [] 

# traverse for all elements 
for x in df: 
    # check if exists in unique_list or not 
    if x in unique_list: 
        unique_list.append(x) 
# print list 
for x in unique_list: 
    print(x)
```

Comment: Just use `set(df['splited_Unique'].tolist())`

Comment: Do you need `df['splited_Unique'].drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: i need to keep unique  only in new column out of this column

Comment: Can you show expected output please? It is hard to understand as it is currently written

Comment: output is to get unique values